# OTRS 5.0.35 js-cache Address book throwing java script error

Tags: javascript, cache

I have upgraded from OTRS 5.0.12 to OTRS 5.0.35.

I am facing issue in opening address book

```
TypeError: $Element.data(...) is undefined

TargetNS.Init@http://intra-dev.wipo.int/otrs-web/js/js-cache/ModuleJS_ef5c62d338501952fb4959c9d98c9867.js:24:179
(?)()@http://intra-dev.wipo.int/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentBook;ToCustomer=;CcCustomer=;BccCustomer=;OTRSAgentInterface=kK5V56wZYHtzItoNbI1KOmTcmIGzW7Cv;OTRSCustomerInterface=kK5V56wZYHtzItoNbI1KOmTcmIGzW7Cv;ChallengeToken=Dt9L7DhwgEt7UpXJ2aqwAzs1OpvdyNsG:353:1
TargetNS.Ready/<@http://intra-dev.wipo.int/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_41e6dd1750ca2fbd57ec666e523008e5.js:1139:120
n.Callbacks/j@http://intra-dev.wipo.int/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_41e6dd1750ca2fbd57ec666e523008e5.js:1:26920
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://intra-dev.wipo.int/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_41e6dd1750ca2fbd57ec666e523008e5.js:1:27738
.ready@http://intra-dev.wipo.int/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_41e6dd1750ca2fbd57ec666e523008e5.js:1:29530
I@http://intra-dev.wipo.int/otrs-web/js/js-cache/CommonJS_41e6dd1750ca2fbd57ec666e523008e5.js:1:29721
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Yes David, I tested after clearing the browser cache. Also I have cleared the js-cache folder in server. 
is there any dependency or parameter that we can use for generating the javascript files in js-cache folder?